# Is this correct ASN.1 syntax?

Tags: asn.1

There is a great ASN.1 tool called asn1c ( https://github.com/vlm/asn1c ).

Sadly when I try to use it on Wireshark's Remote-Operations-Information-Objects ( https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/tree/master/epan/dissectors/asn1/ros ), it fails with the following error:

```
ASN.1 grammar parse error near Remote-Operations-Generic-ROS-PDUs.asn:20 (token "!"): syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting ')'
Cannot parse "Remote-Operations-Generic-ROS-PDUs.asn"
```

Since I'm fairly new to ASN.1, I'd like to ask if this

```
(CONSTRAINED BY { -- must conform to the above definition --} !
 RejectProblem:general-unrecognizedPDU)
```

is actually a correct ASN.1.  I guess it is, since Wireshark's tools/ans2wrs.py parses it successfully. Both tools are said to support the 2002 version of ASN.1.

So:

1. Is this correct ASN.1 ()?
2. Is it some kind of an extension?
3. Can I actually replace that expression with something that wouldn't change the resulting C structures?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this correct ASN.1 ()?

Yes.

To validate it, copy the content of the 3 files in `ros` folder in the left box (schema) of https://asn1.io/asn1playground/ and hit `compile`

> Is it some kind of an extension?

It depends on what you mean by extension.

ASN.1 is a set of documents. 
Free tools usually limit themselves to `Basic Notation` (document x.680) and some `Encoding Rules` (documents x.690, x.691, etc)

The notation the tool you are using is choking on is `Information Object Specification` (document x.681). If you find an open source tool that handles it properly, please add a comment here (I'm very interested)

> Can I actually replace that expression with something that wouldn't change the resulting C structures?

Nope

If you remove the constraint, you will still find plenty of other productions that won't be parsed (OPERATION, parameterized types)

To know more about information objects:

- https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.880-199407-I/en
- https://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-made-simple/advanced-topics.html

EDIT:

Look at this file https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/epan/dissectors/asn1/ros/ros.asn

They have stripped all the information objects and replaced them with deprecated ASN.1 type ANY

```
bind-invoke  [16]  --OPERATION.&ArgumentType({operation})-- ANY
```

May be this is the one to use.